# Run a child form process from parent in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I want to run a MDI child form its parent. For example I have 3 textboxes in the child form. I want to add the two values in the first two text boxes and write the results in the third. I want to have a button on the parent form (lets call it run button) to do this for me. Also, I have other child forms that do other calculations so I want the run button behaves according to the focused form. Does any one know how I should do it?

I have written a method in each child form to do the calculations and I call this method in the run button of the parent form but this does not recognize the values of child form text boxes (ie null). It would be awesome if someone could help me.

Thanks

the code is very simple
I have three text boxes in the child form and the user input values in the first two and I want to click the run button on the parent form and the value of the third text box in the child form becomes the summation of the values of the first two text boxes. I have this method in the child form which I can call it from the parent form but it does not work

```
public void AddValues()
        {
            double a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            double b = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();
        }
```

In the parent form I have

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChildFrom child = new ChildFrom();
            child.AddValues();
        }
```

Comment: Post the code of your child forms

Comment: It can be done, please upload your code.........

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can add the code to your question by editing it. This will improve readability very much ;) Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your child form:

```
public void AddValues() //add error handling
{
    double a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    double b = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();
}
```

In your parent Form you have to call `AddValues` on the same instance of child form which you are opening. In other words, in parent form:

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    ChildForm _cF; //member field

    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenChildForm() //this is how you should open the form
    {                            //call this function in whichever event 
         _cf = new ChildForm();  //you are opening the child form.
         _cf.Show();
    }   

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //please remove these lines, its wrong!
        //ChildFrom child = new ChildFrom();
        //child.AddValues();

        //do this instead:
        _cf.AddValues();
    }
}
```

The key here is to operate on the same instance of the child form. If you need it throughout make it a member field in parent form.

**Edit:**
If you dont wan't child form to be a member variable, then you can rely on closures in C#.

In parent form:

```
private void OpenChildForm()
{
     ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
     cf.Show();

     btnRun.Clicked -= OnRunButtonClicked(cf); //important - to avoid multiple-
     btnRun.Clicked += OnRunButtonClicked(cf); //handlers getting attached.
}  

private EventHandler OnRunButtonClicked(ChildForm cf)
{
    return (sender, e) => cf.AddValues();
}
```

Take care to remove the existing click handler on `btnRun` from the initialization part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works when I am opening the child form but when the child form is already open and the user inputs new values in the textboxes, it does not work. It returns the values of the textboxes as null, although they have values.

Comment: @user1787601 that can never be the case. Do you really have childForm instance as a member field in parent form? You need the same instance to get the `AddValues` function to work. In other words, do not do `ChildForm cf = new ChildForm(); cf.AddValues();` it simply wont work. Do as I posted. Or see my edit if you are not thorough with the idea what a member field is..

Comment: Here is the link of how it looks
http://postimage.org/image/j194eslcd/
I do not want to open the child form. It is already opened in the parent form by clicking the new button. Now in the Run button even I call cf.AddValues() but it give me errors that textboxes are empty while they are not.

Comment: @user1787601 please open the form as I described in my code. Thats all I can say. I agree its already opened, but cant you stop debugging, go back to the code, and re-edit your code? Edit your code which opens the form. Then edit your code under run button click as I have shown in my code.

Comment: @user1787601 I edited the code. You will learn more about objects and classes and instances with time. Good luck! :)

Comment: @user1787601 you should accept the answer by clicking the green tick on the top left of the corner if this helped. That's the right practice to follow in SO

Comment: Sorry I did not know the acceptance procedure.
About the answer, how does it work if I do not directly open the child form from the parent. For example if I have another child form called NewProject form which open when I click the new button in the parent form. Then in the Newproject, I select the type of the project and name and location and this opens a childform accordingly. Thanks again

Comment: I found out how I should do it

Comment: In that case you will have to expose the child form "instance" (which u open from newProject) to parent form, possibly via a public/internal property.